# Making UIPicker pop up when textfield is tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uipicker

I made a application with the templet of a Single View Application. Then I added a label and connected it to the .h file of my ViewController. Then I made a picker, filled it, then set it (and a toolBar I made) to the textfield. But when I tap the textfield, the picker is just all black. If this made no sense, the code will explain it all.

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *habitField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *PickerData;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    self.PickerData = array;

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];

    [toolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_navigation_bar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(releasePicker)];

    UIPickerView *Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

    doneButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, doneButton] animated:YES];
    self.habitField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.PickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.PickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

The simulator looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you forgot to set delegate for picker ( UIPickerViewDelegate )

```
        Picker.delegate = self;
```

Remember to add :)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate> {
```

}

Cheers